# Activity indicator slows function considerably

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

Has anyone else had this problem? I have a function that depending on situation needs time and sometimes executes very fast. This function is called when a new View Controller is displayed so in order to let the user see that the function is executing I'm using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{` to execute the function in a new thread and at the same time display the new View Controller and Activity Indicator.

It works as I expected but on certain occasions when the function should execute almost instantly it still takes almost 3 sec. before the Activity Indicator disappears and content is displayed. It seems that never mind the situation it always takes the same time (3sec) but when I execute it in main thread there are only limited times when it takes that long.

Comment: You shouldn't use any UIKit classes (such as `UIActivityIndicatorView`) from a background thread/queue. UIKit is for the most part main thread-only.

Comment: If you want it to go faster, don't use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW`.  try `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` or `HIGH` instead.  You shouldn't affect main thread performance on the global queues (even the HIGH).  That's what they are there for.

Comment: @amattn Yeah, I tried DEFAULT or HIGH but that didn't work

Comment: @omz Are You saying that the problem is that I have UIKit elements in the function (which I do). So there should only be calculations??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As omz points out, most UIKit classes are not thread-safe, and anything involving your UI should happen on the main thread. The correct way to do some arbitrarily-long-running thing on another queue while showing an activity indicator looks like this:

```
[self showProgressUIOrWhatever];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doSomeWork];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideProgressUIOrWhatever];
    });
});
```

Comment: Wiherspoon Thanks for the answer. I'm actually saying `[activityView stopAnimating]` inside the thirdTabClicked function. When I put the `[activityView stopAnimating]` like You showed the Activity Indicator disappears too early and it takes ca 2 sec for the content elements to display

Comment: If by “the content elements to display” you mean, e.g., reloading a table view, then that also needs to be inside the main-queue block. It’s not just activity indicators.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reloading CollectionView as well creating Labels and UIImageViews, so this seems to be the reason, why it is so slow in background thread.

Comment: It’s not an issue of speed, per se—your UI just sort of doesn’t know to update itself when you’ve created these things off the main thread. If you move your `UI*` operations to the main-queue block, you’ll see the results much faster.